# How can I generate an ID column for a column in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I have a column that I'd like to generate an ID column for. How can I do this using SQL?. Also, is it possible to specify what type of ID I'd like to have as well as length. e.g. letters+ numbers or simply numbers?.

Thank you.

I am using SQL Server and SSMS.

Comment: Start here:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql-identity-property?view=sql-server-ver16

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has two ways to create primary key in SQL Server:

1. First in the table like his:

```
CREATE TABLE Persons (
    ID int NOT NULL,
    LastName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    FirstName varchar(255),
    Age int,
    CONSTRAINT PK_Person PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);
```

2. On altering table like:

```
ALTER TABLE Persons
ADD PRIMARY KEY (ID);
```

NB: Only for the number ID column, add IDENTITY(1,1) if you want the
number increment automatically like:

```
CREATE TABLE Persons (
    Personid IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL ,
    PRIMARY KEY (Personid)
);
```

Comment: If I had a table where I needed to create more than one column of ID keys. Would I still use the same line repeated for all columns: ID int NOT NULL?

Comment: rapha123 if you need to create more than one column of ID keys, use like this PRIMARY KEY (ID,firstName,LastName)